# Update Alfresco workflow properties during transition

Tags: alfresco

I want to update custom workflow properties(workflowStatus) in task transition.
In detail, when I approve the workflows workflowStatus changed to "Approved", and at the time I reject, this property changed to "Rejected".

How can I do??
Writing with Javascript or other separate java file like AlfrescoJavaScript??
I use jbpm workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can solve it. I write my own action class for each transition such as CustomWorkflowApprove and CustomWorkflowReject.
In these class I update workflow properties.
Part of my processdefinition.xml is as follows:

```
<task-node name="approve2">
<task name="dmswf:reviewTask2" swimlane="approver2">
    <event type="task-create">
        <script>
            if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
            if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
        </script>
    </event>
</task>
<transition name="approve" to="approved" >
    <action class="org.ace.dms.bean.CustomWorkflowApprove"/>
</transition>
    <transition name="reject" to="rejected" >
        <action class="org.ace.dms.bean.CustomWorkflowReject"/>
    </transition>
</task-node>
```

This is my CustomWorkflowAction class.

```
    package org.ace.dms.bean;

    import org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.JBPMSpringActionHandler;
    import org.jbpm.graph.exe.ExecutionContext;

    public abstract class CustomWorkflowAction extends JBPMSpringActionHandler {

        public static final String APPROVE = "Approved";
        public static final String REJECT = "Rejected";
        public static final String WORKFLOWSTATUS = "dmswf_workflowStatus";

        public void updateWorkflowProperties(ExecutionContext context,
                String workflowStatus) {
//update custom workflow property dmswf_workflowStatus, you can update any workflow property here
            context.setVariable(WORKFLOWSTATUS, workflowStatus);
        }
    }
```

This is my CustomWorkflowApprove class.

```
package org.ace.dms.bean;

import org.jbpm.graph.exe.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

public class CustomWorkflowApprove extends CustomWorkflowAction {

    @Override
    public void execute(ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
        updateWorkflowProperties(context, CustomWorkflowAction.APPROVE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialiseHandler(BeanFactory factory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Initialzize Handler");
    }

}
```